# T-SQL-Procedure - Try...Catch not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, try-catch

I am developing a Data-Warehouse on SQL Server 2019.
I have a stored procedure that queries data from a different database and inserts the data into my Data-Warehouse.
Therefore I am working with a try...catch that is supposed to rollback the transaction in case of an error and insert the error-values into a different table.

Here is a code sample:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TheProcedure
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO
            dbo.DestinationTable(Data)
        SELECT
            Data
        FROM
            dbo.SourceTable
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1 COMMIT TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO dbo.ErrorTable
    VALUES
    (
    SUSER_SNAME(),
    ERROR_NUMBER(),
    ERROR_STATE(),
    ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    ERROR_LINE(),
    ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
    ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    GETDATE()
    );
    DECLARE
    @Message VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    @Severity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @State SMALLINT = ERROR_STATE()
    EXECUTE dbo.AnotherProcedure
    RAISERROR (@Message, @Severity, @State)
END CATCH

END
```

On some errors like a foreign key constraint violation the catch seems to work and inserts the error-values into the ErrorTable. However there are errors where the it seems to me that the catch is not even activated.
For example if I misspell "DestinationTable" (i. e.  "NonExistentTable") and the procedure cant find the table it is supposed to insert into, the procedure is cancelled with an error message. However the catch is not being executed, because no error-values are being inserted into the ErrorTable:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO
            dbo.NonExistentTable(Data)
        SELECT
            Data
        FROM
            dbo.SourceTable
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I have already read several posts to this topic on StackOverFlow as well as on other sites google provided me with, but i cant seem to get the logic nor the solution behind this problem.

Thank you very much in advance,

Best Regards

Comment: `TRY...CATCH` doesn't catch stuff like that. It's not *not* working; it's working exactly as expected. A T-SQL statement is parsed and compiled *before* it is run, and at *that* point the error occurs; well before the statement is run and the `TRY...CATCH` is entered.

Comment: From [Errors Unaffected by a TRY...CATCH Construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-unaffected-by-a-trycatch-construct): *"The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY...CATCH construct: ... **Object name resolution errors***

Comment: Erland has a longer discussion of [error handling](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). A good website to bookmark and review

Comment: It's a bit like saying that a C# compile error is not being caught in a `catch`. It's not even running the code, it's still trying to compile it

Comment: How do you expect [this to be handled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJG6G.png)? SQL Server needs to validate that the script makes sense and references valid entities etc. before it starts worrying about your error handling.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses!!

I wrote the previous code to demonstrate the problem, but it is not the actual problem. In other words every now and then there seems to be an error that is not being handled by the Catch, but i dont know what the error is, i only see that something stopped the procedure without performing the Catch.
Ive read about possible issues like hardware failure etc. that are not being affected by the catch, but i do not believe that an error like that is responsible.

Comment: So you have an error, but you don't know what the error is, and you don't know what is happening to produce the error, but the above SQL you've given isn't actually related to the code you are using to get said error..? So... What do you want us to do? With respect, we can't exactly pull an answer out of a hat here. You'll need to debug your code first and get the error first. Then I would suggest trying to create a [mre], and if you then can't fix that then post a (new) question about said problem.